# How to consume secured arcgis map (role based active directory users) with SharePoint?

Tags: arcmap

What is the best way to consume a secured arcgis map with sharepoint?

Answer (score 2):

ESRI's [help topic on SharePoint](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/sharepoint/2.1/help/index.html#//015900000046000000) includes a section about **Adding Secured Services to the Map Web Part**. Have you followed this, and are there specific problems/errors you've encountered?